# Long texts maintenance via SM30

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I need to store long text data in a Z-table and maintain the data manually. Is there any way to maintain the texts via se54 generated dialogs? If no I will develope an ALV table report to maintain the table/long texts data of course...

Comment: Please specify how you need/want to store the text - STRING, SO10 text, ...?

Comment: It's optional. I can use really all of the ways you mentioned.

Comment: Use SO10 for maintaining standard texts. No need to (re)invent the wheel.

Comment: I will have ~100 records in the Z-table. It means the user must call SO10 for each record...